# Metal bracket popping out at the entrance of steering shaft near the brake pedal

Tags: nissan, part-identification, steering

I have a 2009 Nissan Versa. While making a turn, I heard a metallic snapping/clanking noise, which I could feel at my feet as well as in the wheel. I discovered what looks like a metal bracket popping out at the entrance of steering shaft near the brake pedal.

Turning the wheel, it appears to be attached by a bolt and moves when I turn. I'm not sure if I should drive my car to a mechanic or have it towed as I'm unsure what this bracket was holding on to on the inside. Have any ideas what this might be?

[image]

Comment: Seems like more than one person has experienced this and everyone is just cutting off the metal bracket. Fingers crossed that it's not important.
http://www.nissanversaforums.com/interior-forum/13746-loud-clicking-steering-shaft-when-turning.html

Comment: You need to document that as the answer with the links you provided. Good catch and I don't blame you for cutting it off.